# Detecting specific error from multi-error type

Tags: session, go, cookies, error-handling, gorilla

Trying to differentiate from a bad user-cookie error vs. an internal error using `gorilla/sessions` e.g.

```
import "github.com/gorilla/sessions"

sess, err := store.Get(r, sessName)
if err != nil {
    // either user error (bad-cookie i.e. invalid HMAC)
    //      http.Error(w, "not authenticated", http.StatusUnauthorized)

    // or server error (FileSystemStore i/o)
    //      http.Error(w, "internal error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

The underlying `securecookie` package has an exported error `ErrMacInvalid` for bad user cookies. So ordinarily one would just check for this specific error, but this does **not** work:

```
import "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"

if err == securecookie.ErrMacInvalid {
    // bad user-cookie
} else if err != nil {
    // otherwise internal error
}
```

The reason it does not work - using say `securecookie.NewCookieStore()` as a session store - is it will return a error of type [securecookie.MultiError](https://github.com/gorilla/securecookie/blob/master/securecookie.go#L605) 
 (a `[]error` type) with the `securecookie.ErrMacInvalid` value listed within the error slice.

Trying something like this seems very convoluted:

```
if e2, ok := err.(securecookie.MultiError); ok && len(e2) > 0 && e2[0] == securecookie.ErrMacInvalid { {
    // bad user-cookie
} else if err != nil {
    // otherwise internal error
}
```

is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there an easier way?

No. Sorry.

Comment: Odd the package would have an exported error `securecookie.ErrMacInvalid` that is so hard to check. Not sure what problem the  `MultiError` type is trying to solve, as it just seems to complicate client code. Even the Cause() method seems to admit how useless it is.